# Vector Errors in C++ Program

Tags: c++, vector, compiler-errors

I am currently working on just a miscellaneous Theater Seating program! I am just starting to progress through C++, but I can't figure out these errors. I am trying to make the program store user entered row numbers and row seats (only if it is multiple seats) in two vectors; vector seat_row() and vector seat_number(). I know what the error is stating, but I don't know how to approach the situation otherwise. Sorry if I am being too unclear, but to be honest, I don't know what else to include. Please take a look at my code, get a feel for my program, and let me have any ideas. Please keep answers somewhat simple; again, I'm no master at C++

P.S.

Sorry for showing the whole code... I didn't really know what to include, what not to; and I wanted people to be able to get a feel for the program by even testing it themselves... Thanks again!

```
/* 
 * This is a program built by a team of students
 * to help local movie theaters sell tickets
 * 
 * File: main.cpp
 * Author(s):
 *
 * 
 * Created on April 15, 2013, 11:10 AM
 */


#include <cstdlib>
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>
#include <cctype>
#include <iomanip>

using namespace std;

//Function Prototypes
void Title_Card();
void seating_prices();
void seating_chart();
void pick_seating();
void purchase_history();
void quit();
void update_file();
void Show_Menu();
void picking_seats();
void display_seating();
void display_name();
void display_number_of_seats();
void display_correct1(string, int);
void display_seats();
void display_correct2(string, int, int, int);
void display_correct2_alt(string, int, vector<int>, vector<int>);
void display_correct3(string);
void multiple_seats(string, int, vector<int>, vector<int>);
void display_rows_seats(string, int);
void display_finished(string);
void display_purchase_seats(string, int, int);
void display_purchase_seats_alt(string, int, vector<int>, vector<int>);

int readSeating (const char*, vector<char>&); //Reads SeatingChart.txt
int readPrices(string, vector<double>&); //Reads SeatingPrices.txt
vector<double> prices(15); //For SeatPrices.txt
vector<char> seating(450); //For SeatingChart.txt

vector<int> seat_row(); //For storing multiple seat rows
vector<int> seat_number(); //For storing multiple seat numbers



//Actual Program
int main() {
    Title_Card(); //Calls Title Page

    readSeating("SeatingChart.txt", seating); //Reads SeatingChart.txt
    readPrices("SeatPrices.txt", prices); //Reads SeatPrices.txt
    Show_Menu(); //Shows Introductory Menu

    system ("pause");
    return 0;
}




//**************************************************************
// Definition of the ShowMenu function. Shows introductory menu*
// and controls where user ends up in the program.             *
//**************************************************************


void Show_Menu() {
int choice;
string password;

      cout << "Welcome to the our theater program! Made for a person" << endl;
      cout << "who is looking for seating, purchasing a ticket, and" << endl;
      cout << "searching for other miscellaneous things... We hope" << endl;
      cout << "you enjoy the program!" << endl << endl;
      cout << "Below is a list of options the user can choose from:" << endl << endl;
      cout << "1.\tSeating Prices" << endl;
      cout << "2.\tSeating Chart" << endl;
      cout << "3.\tPick Seating" << endl;
      cout << "4.\tPurchase History" << endl;
      cout << "5.\tQuit" << endl << endl;
      cout << "Enter a choice... (1-5): ";
      cin >> choice; 


      while (choice < 1 || choice > 5){
            cout << endl << "You have entered an invalid choice!" << endl;
            cout << "Enter a choice... (1-5): ";
            cin >> choice;

                }


        switch (choice){
             case 1:
                  seating_prices();

             case 2:
                  seating_chart();

             case 3:
                  pick_seating();

             case 4:
                  purchase_history();

             case 5:
                  quit();
                  }
                  }






//**************************************************************
// Definition of the seating_prices function. Displays to the  *
// user, SeatPrices.txt                                        *
//**************************************************************


void seating_prices(){
    system ("cls");
    cout << "The Current Seating Prices Are:" << endl << endl;
    for (int count = 0; count < 4; count++){
    cout << " " << setprecision(4) << showpoint <<  prices[count] << " | Row " << (count + 1) << endl;
    }
    for (int count = 4; count < prices.size(); count++){
    cout << "  " << setprecision(3) << showpoint <<  prices[count] << " | Row " << (count + 1) << endl;
    }
    cout << endl;
    system ("pause");
    system ("cls");
    Show_Menu();
}



//**************************************************************
// Definition of the seating_chart function. Function for      *
// displaying the seating chart by itself                      *
//**************************************************************

void seating_chart(){

     system ("cls");
     int counter = 30;
     int row_counter = 0;


    cout << "The Current Seating Chart Is:" << endl << endl << endl << "           1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 0" << endl << endl;
    cout << "         ---------------------------------------------------------------" << endl; 
    cout << " Row " << (row_counter + 1) << "     ";

    //Displaying Seating Chart
     for (int index = 0; index < 270; index++){



         if (index == counter){
            row_counter = (row_counter + 1);
            counter = (counter + 30);
            cout << "" << endl << " Row " << (row_counter + 1) << "     ";

            }

         cout << seating[index] << " ";
         }     



     for (int index = 270; index < seating.size(); index++){

         if (index == counter){
            row_counter = (row_counter + 1);
            counter = (counter + 30);
            cout << "" << endl << " Row " << (row_counter + 1) << "    ";

            }

         cout << seating[index] << " ";
         }
     cout << endl << "         ---------------------------------------------------------------" << endl; 

         cout << endl << endl;
         system ("pause");
         system ("cls");
         Show_Menu();
         }




//**************************************************************
// Definition of the pick_seating function. Displays the       *
// current seating chart and allows the user to pick their seat*
//**************************************************************


void pick_seating(){  //Not Finished

    system ("cls");
    display_seating();

}




//**************************************************************
// Definition of the purchase_history function. Displays the   *
// current the total sum of all movie ticket purchases         *
//**************************************************************


void purchase_history(){         //Not finished
     system ("cls");
     system ("pause");
     system ("cls");
     Show_Menu();
}



//**************************************************************
// Definition of the quit function. Allows the user to quit the*
// program entirely                                            *
//**************************************************************


void quit(){
     update_file();
     exit(0);
     }




//**************************************************************
// Definition of the update_file function. Designed to update  *
// the seating chart upon leaving the pick_seating function    *
//**************************************************************



void update_file(){  //Not finished

     //This function is supposed to
     //Update the seating chart
     //upon exit of the pick_seating function
     }




//**************************************************************
// Definition of the read_Prices function. Reads SeatPrices.txt  *
// and stores the pre-determined prices into a vector named    *
// prices.                                                     *
//**************************************************************



int readPrices(string myFile, vector<double>& vect) {

    //input file
    ifstream SeatPrices;                   

    SeatPrices.open(myFile.c_str());


    //if file cannot be found
    if (!SeatPrices) 
    cout << "Cannot find the file!" << endl;


    for (int index = 0; index < vect.size(); index++){
        SeatPrices >> vect[index];   //Reading the file "SeatPrices.txt"
        }

    SeatPrices.close();  //Closes the file
    return 0;
}




//**************************************************************
// Definition of the readSeating function. Reads a text file   *
// with a seating chart in it.                                 *
//**************************************************************



int readSeating(const char* myFile, vector<char>& vect){


    //input file
    ifstream SeatingChart;
    SeatingChart.open(myFile);

    //if file cannot be found
    if (!SeatingChart)
    cout << "Cannot find the file!" << endl;

    for (int index = 0; index < vect.size(); index++){
        SeatingChart >> vect[index];  //Reading the file "SeatingChart.txt"
        }

    SeatingChart.close(); //Closes the file
    return 0;
}




//**************************************************************
// Definition of the display_seating function. Function for    *
// simplifying the pick_seating function                       *
//**************************************************************


void display_seating(){

     int counter = 30;
     int row_counter = 0;


    //Displaying Seating Chart
    cout << "           1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 0" << endl << endl;
    cout << "         ---------------------------------------------------------------" << endl; 
    cout << " Row " << (row_counter + 1) << "     ";

    //Displaying Seating Chart
     for (int index = 0; index < 270; index++){



         if (index == counter){
            row_counter = (row_counter + 1);
            counter = (counter + 30);
            cout << "" << endl << " Row " << (row_counter + 1) << "     ";

            }

         cout << seating[index] << " ";
         }     



     for (int index = 270; index < seating.size(); index++){

         if (index == counter){
            row_counter = (row_counter + 1);
            counter = (counter + 30);
            cout << "" << endl << " Row " << (row_counter + 1) << "    ";

            }

         cout << seating[index] << " ";
         }
     cout << endl << "         ---------------------------------------------------------------" << endl << endl; 

     cout << "In the seating chart... All hashtags (#'s) are seats already taken" << endl;
     cout << "and all stars (*'s) are available seats..." << endl << endl;
     system ("pause");


     display_name(); //Continues the program, helps loop if necessary
     }



//**************************************************************
// Definition of the display_name function. Function for       *
// simplifying the pick_seating function                       *
//**************************************************************


void display_name(){

     string name;

     //Picking your seat
    cout << endl << endl << "To pick your own seat(s), follow the instructions below:" << endl << endl;
    cout << "What is the name of the recipient of the seat(s)? ";
    cin >> name;


    display_correct3(name);
    }



//**************************************************************
// Definition of the display_number_of_seats function. Function*
// for simplifying the pick_seating function                   *
//**************************************************************


void display_number_of_seats(string name){

     int number_of_seats;
     int available_seats = 450; //Amount of remaining seats out of 450

     cout << "Alright " << name << "!" << endl;
     cout << "How many seats are you purchasing today? ";
     cin >> number_of_seats;

        while (number_of_seats < 1 || number_of_seats > available_seats){
              cout << endl << endl << "You have entered an invalid number of seats!" << endl;
              cout << "This might be because your number is zero or less," << endl;
              cout << "or that the number you entered is more than the amount" << endl;
              cout << "of remaining seats! Try again!" << endl << endl;
              cout << "How many seats are you purchasing today? ";
              cin >> number_of_seats;
              }

        display_correct1(name, number_of_seats);
        }


//**************************************************************
// Definition of the display_correct1 function. Function for   *
// simplifying the pick_seating function                       *
//**************************************************************


void display_correct1(string name, int number_of_seats){

     int correct;

     cout << endl << "Alright " << name << ", you are purchasing " << number_of_seats << " seat(s)?" << endl;
     cout << "Is this correct? Enter a '0' for 'no', or a '1' for yes: ";
     cin >> correct;

        while (correct < 0 || correct > 1){
        cout << "You have entered an invalid number!" << endl;
        cout << "Enter a '0' for 'no', or a '1' for yes: ";
        cin >> correct;
        }

        if (correct == 0){
           cout << endl << endl;
           display_number_of_seats(name);
           }

        if (correct == 1){
           cout << endl << endl;

           if (number_of_seats > 1)
           multiple_seats(name, number_of_seats, seat_row, seat_number);

           display_rows_seats(name, number_of_seats);
           }



     }




//**************************************************************
// Definition of the multiple_seats function. Function only    *
// used if user chooses to purchase multiple seats             *
//**************************************************************


void multiple_seats(string name, int number_of_seats, vector<int> vect, vector<int> vect2){

     for (int index = 1; index <= number_of_seats; index++){

     for (int count = 0; count < number_of_seats; count++){

     cout << "For Seat #" << index << "..." << endl;

     cout << "Enter the row number you would like to be in: (1-15): ";             
     cin >> vect[count];

         while (vect[count] < 1 || vect[count] > 15){
          cout << endl << "You have entered an invalid row number!" << endl;
          cout << "Enter the row number you would like to be in (1-15): ";
          cin >> vect[count];
          }

          cout << "Enter the seat number you would like to have (1-30): ";
          cin >> vect2[count];

              while (vect2[count] < 1 || vect2[count] > 30){
              cout << endl << "You have entered an invalid seat number!" << endl;
              cout << "Enter the seat number you would like to have (1-30): ";
              cin >> vect2[count];
              }
     cout << endl;
     }
     }
     display_correct2_alt(name, number_of_seats, seat_row, seat_number);
     }




//**************************************************************
// Definition of the display_rows_seats function. Function for *
// simplifying the pick_seating function                       *
//**************************************************************

void display_rows_seats(string name, int number_of_seats){

     int seat_choice;
     int row_choice; 

     cout << "Enter the row number you would like to be in: (1-15): ";             
     cin >> row_choice;

         while (row_choice < 1 || row_choice > 15){
          cout << endl << "You have entered an invalid row number!" << endl;
          cout << "Enter the row number you would like to be in (1-15): ";
          cin >> row_choice;
          }

          cout << "Enter the seat number you would like to have (1-30): ";
          cin >> seat_choice;

              while (seat_choice < 1 || seat_choice > 30){
              cout << endl << "You have entered an invalid seat number!" << endl;
              cout << "Enter the seat number you would like to have (1-30): ";
              cin >> seat_choice;
              }

     display_correct2(name, number_of_seats, row_choice, seat_choice); //Helps looping if necessary

     }




//**************************************************************
// Definition of the display_correct2_alt function. Alternate  *
// function if user enters multiple seats                      *
//**************************************************************


void display_correct2_alt(string name, int number_of_seats, vector<int> vect, vector<int> vect2){

     int correct;
     int counter = 1;
     int counter_2 = 1; //For minor details for looks

     for (int index = 1; index <= number_of_seats; index++){  

     for (int count = 0; count < number_of_seats; count++){


     if (counter_2 != number_of_seats && counter_2 == 1){         //For first seat

     cout << endl << endl << "Alright " << name << ";" << endl;
     cout << "For Seat #" << index << "; you chose " << "Row #" << vect[count];
     cout << " and Seat #" << vect2[count] << "?" << endl;
     cout << "Is this correct? Enter a '0' for 'no', or a '1' for yes: ";
     cin >> correct;

     }


     if (counter_2 != number_of_seats && counter_2 > 1){         //For all seats after first, except last seat

     cout << endl << endl;
     cout << "Next, for Seat #" << index << "; you chose " << "Row #" << vect[count];
     cout << " and Seat #" << vect2[count] << "?" << endl;
     cout << "Is this correct? Enter a '0' for 'no', or a '1' for yes: ";
     cin >> correct;

     }


     if (counter_2 == number_of_seats){         //For last seat

     cout << endl << endl;
     cout << "And for your last seat, Seat #" << index << "; you chose " << "Row #" << vect[count];
     cout << " and Seat #" << vect2[count] << "?" << endl;
     cout << "Is this correct? Enter a '0' for 'no', or a '1' for yes: ";
     cin >> correct;
     }
     }



        while (correct < 0 || correct > 1){
        cout << "You have entered an invalid number!" << endl;
        cout << "Enter a '0' for 'no', or a '1' for yes: ";
        cin >> correct;
        }


        if (correct == 0){
           cout << endl << endl;

           if (number_of_seats > 1)
           multiple_seats(name, number_of_seats, seat_row, seat_number);

           display_rows_seats(name, number_of_seats);
           }

        if (correct == 1){
           if (counter == number_of_seats)
           display_purchase_seats_alt(name, number_of_seats, seat_row, seat_number);
           }

        counter = (counter + 1);
        counter_2 = (counter_2 + 1);

     }
     }


//**************************************************************
// Definition of the display_correct2 function. Function for   *
// simplifying the pick_seating function                       *
//**************************************************************


void display_correct2(string name, int number_of_seats, int row_choice, int seat_choice){

     int correct;

     cout << endl << endl << "Alright " << name << ", you chose " << "Row #" << row_choice;
     cout << " and Seat #" << seat_choice << "?" << endl;
     cout << "Is this correct? Enter a '0' for 'no', or a '1' for yes: ";
     cin >> correct;

        while (correct < 0 || correct > 1){
        cout << "You have entered an invalid number!" << endl;
        cout << "Enter a '0' for 'no', or a '1' for yes: ";
        cin >> correct;
        }

        if (correct == 0){
           cout << endl << endl;

           if (number_of_seats > 1)
           multiple_seats(name, number_of_seats, seat_row, seat_number);

           display_rows_seats(name, number_of_seats);
           }

        if (correct == 1)
           display_purchase_seats(name, row_choice, seat_choice);



     }




//**************************************************************
// Definition of the display_purchase_seats function. Function *
// user to purchase his chosen seats                           *
//**************************************************************


void display_purchase_seats(string name, int row_choice, int seat_choice){

     int total_cost = 0; //Not set up yet; supposed to calculate the row price

     system ("cls");
     cout << name << ", now it is time to pay for your chosen seats!" << endl;
     cout << "Since you chose Row #" << row_choice << ", and Seat# " << seat_choice << "..." << endl;
     cout << "Your total cost is: S" << total_cost << endl << endl;

     system ("pause"); 
     display_finished(name);
     }




//**************************************************************
// Definition of the display_purchase_seats_alt function.      *
// Alternate function used for purchasing multiple seats       *
//**************************************************************


void display_purchase_seats_alt(string name, int number_of_seats, vector<int> vect, vector<int> vect2){

     int total_cost = 0; //Not set up yet; supposed to calculate the row price

     system ("cls");
     cout << name << ", now it is time to pay for your chosen seats!" << endl;
     cout << "Since you chose " << number_of_seats << " seats:" << endl << endl;

     for (int index = 0; index <= number_of_seats; index++){

     cout << "Seat #" << index << " being in Row #" << seat_row[index] << ";" << endl;
     }

     cout << endl << "Your total cost is: $" << total_cost << endl << endl;
     system ("pause"); 
     display_finished(name);
     }     


//**************************************************************
// Definition of the display_correct3 function. Function for   *
// simplifying the pick_seating function                       *
//**************************************************************


void display_correct3(string name){

     int correct;

     cout << endl << "Alright, you chose the name " << name << "?" << endl;
     cout << "Is this correct? Enter a '0' for 'no', or a '1' for yes: ";
     cin >> correct;

        while (correct < 0 || correct > 1){
        cout << "You have entered an invalid number!" << endl;
        cout << "Enter a '0' for 'no', or a '1' for yes: ";
        cin >> correct;
        }

        if (correct == 0){
           system ("cls");
           display_seating();
           }

        if (correct == 1){
           cout << endl;
           display_number_of_seats(name); //Helps if looping is necessary
           }



     }




//**************************************************************
// Definition of the display_finished function. Function for   *
// simplifying the pick_seating function                       *
//**************************************************************


void display_finished(string name){

     system ("cls");

     cout << "Congratulations " << name << "! You have picked your seat!" << endl;
     cout << "The Seating Chart will update momentarily..." << endl << endl;
     update_file();
     system ("pause");
     system ("cls");
     Show_Menu();

     }



//**************************************************************
// Definition of the Title_Card function. Starts the program   *
// with a title card, showing a little introductory title      *
//**************************************************************


void Title_Card(){
     cout << endl << endl << endl << endl;
     cout << "\t\t" << "************************************************\n";
     cout << "\t\t" << "*               THEATER SEATING!               *\n";
     cout << "\t\t" << "*                                              *\n";
     cout << "\t\t" << "*     A program created by a team of three     *\n";
     cout << "\t\t" << "*     students to help small theaters sell     *\n";
     cout << "\t\t" << "*                 more tickets                 *\n";
     cout << "\t\t" << "*                                              *\n";
     cout << "\t\t" << "*              Team of Students:               *\n";
     cout << "\t\t" << "*                                              *\n";
     cout << "\t\t" << "*                                              *\n";
     cout << "\t\t" << "*                                              *\n";
     cout << "\t\t" << "*                                              *\n";
     cout << "\t\t" << "*                                              *\n";
     cout << "\t\t" << "************************************************\n";
     cout << endl << endl;
     system ("pause");
     system ("cls");
     }
```

Comment: It's great that yiouve shared code but it helps us and you a lot if you can reduce it to a minimal but still complete example rather than your whole project.

Comment: No one here is willing to look through 800 lines of code.

Comment: I don't know, when the code really is complete (as in this example) it's straightforward to cut and paste. The OP could have quoted the error message however.

Comment: @chris. Yeah, I actually am sincerely sorry... But in the situation of my program... It would take hours just to cut down to where I think the problem is, which I don't even know "if I know" where the problem is... Though thanks for looking at the question

Comment: @john. You are absolutely right... I forgot about quoting it... I am obviously new to SO. Thanks again

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your error is here

```
vector<int> seat_row(); //For storing multiple seat rows
vector<int> seat_number(); //For storing multiple seat numbers
```

it should be

```
vector<int> seat_row; //For storing multiple seat rows
vector<int> seat_number; //For storing multiple seat numbers
```

It's a very common error, you were trying to declare two vectors called seat_row and seat_number, but because you used empty parens instead you declared two *functions* which return vectors.

Here's a summary

```
vector<int> a(10); // vector, size 10
vector<int> b(0);  // vector, size 0
vector<int> c;     // also vector size 0
vector<int> d();   // FUNCTION!! taking no arguments and returning a vector
```

Comment: WOW! Thanks so much man! I feel beyond ignorant at the moment... But thanks for debugging it! Much appreciated!